# show $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)=x-\ln(e^x-1)$

Tags: graphing-functions, inverse

$f(x)=f^{-1}(x)=x-\ln(e^x-1)$, letting $f^{-1}$ denote the invese of $f$.

I have no idea how to show this algebraically and any Calculus methods I tried failed in horrible differential equations like $y'+e^y=1$ so I'm not sure.

It seems to work though https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yjktqiv1kz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming  $f^{-1}$ exists:

$y= x - \ln(\exp(x)-1)$, $x>0.$

Solve for $x$:

$\exp(y) = \exp(x)(\exp(x) -1)^{-1}.$

Set $z=\exp(x):$

$(z-1)\exp(y)=z;$

$z(\exp(y) -1) =\exp(y).$

$z= \exp(y)(\exp(y)-1)^{-1}.$

$x= \ln(z)= y -\ln(\exp(y)-1)$.

Comment: Could you explain the step from $(z−1)exp(y)=z$ to $z(exp(y)−1)=exp(y)$

Comment: Apropos 0 sence: (z-1)exp(y) = z; then: z exp(y) -exp(y)=z; then: z exp(y) -z = exp(y): then : z(exp(y)-1)=exp(y).

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want to verify that $f^{-1}=f$? All this means is that
$f(f(x))=x$. But
\begin{align}
f(f(x))&=f(x)-\ln(\exp(f(x))-1)\\
&=x-\ln(e^x-1)-\ln(e^x/(e^x-1)-1)\\
&=x-\ln(e^x-1)-\ln(1/(e^x-1))\\
&=\cdots
\end{align}etc.

Comment: if you pull out a negative from the $\ln$ terms, use the addition to multiplication rule, you get the $\ln$ terms equal to $0$, leaving $x$. Not sure why you're inferring this is a counterexample. Thanks though.